# Data not showing in chart..just display blank C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

hello guys i want to graph the data that i have get in the database.
but it displays nothing and no error also, when a trace it using a breakpoint it works fine.

is this how to do it or is there other way to do it because i need to put it on a list so that the data from database will be decrypted cause it is encrypted.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select s.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, YEAR(SalesDate)as year, ISNULL(sum(s.Qty), 0.0) as total from Sales as s inner join Products as p on p.ProductID = s.ProductID WHERE Status = 'Sold' GROUP BY YEAR(SalesDate),s.ProductID, p.ProductDesc ", sqlconn);
        SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<int> total = new List<int>();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            list.Add(Cryptor.Decode(dr["ProductDesc"].ToString()));
            total.Add(int.Parse(dr["total"].ToString()));
            
        }
        Series s1 = chartSales.Series["Series1"];
        s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
        s1.Name = "Sales";
        
        
        
        foreach (string i in list)
        {
            chartSales.Series["Sales"].XValueMember = i;
        }
        foreach(int i in total)
        {
            chartSales.Series["Sales"].YValueMembers = i.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Cold you produce a [mcve], please? At the moment you've not made it clear if the issue is with the SQL query or with the chart, so it would be better if you can narrow it down to one or the other and just ask about that.

Comment: @Llama no issue in the query, i just need to decrypt the `ProductDesc` column before adding to a chart, thats y i decrypt it and add it on a list

Comment: Then I suggest removing the SQL and decryption components of your question and simply create a `List<string> list` and `List<int> total` with hard-coded values. As there's no issue with the query, or with decoding? decrypting? (not the same thing...) the data, all you should need for a [mcve] are the values and the chart code, right?